# How to check if 2 strings are equal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in JS and trying to sort some cars by their model. The models are sorted by ranking in this order (Mercedes, BMW, Jeep, Nissan). I would like it to be case-insensitive. I went about it by creating a variable for creating the desired rankings.

```
var modelRanking = function(car) {
  if (car.model.toLowerCase() === 'mercedes') {
      return 1;
  } else if (car.model.toLowerCase() === 'bmw') {
      return 2;
  } else if (car.model.toLowerCase() === 'jeep') {
     return 3;
  } else if (car.model.toLowerCase() === 'nissan') {
     return 4;
  } else {
     return 5;
  }
}

function modelComparator(car1, car2) {
  if (car1.modelRanking < car2.modelRanking) {
     return true;
  } else if (car1.modelRanking > car2.modelRanking) {
     return false;
  } else if (car1.modelRanking == car2.modelRanking) {
     return yearComparator(car1, car2);
  }
}
```

However the modelRanking is always returning 5.

Comment: Where are you using the `modelRanking` function. Does that property exist?

Comment: you should pass your car as argumment: `modelRanking(car1)` `modelRanking(car2)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `car1.modelRanking`, use `modelRanking(car1)` because modelRanking is a function in global scope, not a property of car1.

```
function modelComparator(car1, car2) {
  if (modelRanking(car1) < modelRanking(car2)) {
     return true;
  } else if (modelRanking(car1) > modelRanking(car2)) {
     return false;
  } else if (modelRanking(car1) == modelRanking(car2)) {
     return yearComparator(car1, car2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow can't believe I did that. Seems like my mind is still stuck in Python. Thanks a bunch!